# How to shuffle columns independently

Tags: r

How to shuffle/permute/randomize with R values independently in all columns in big data frame and remain order of columns. Example:

```
> M
  head1 head2 head3
1     1     a     A
2     2     b     B
3     3     c     C
4     4     d     D

> M
  head1 head2 head3
1     2     b     D
2     4     a     A
3     1     d     B
4     3     c     C
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to probably just use `lapply` and `sample`, like this:

```
M[] <- lapply(M, sample)
```

Or, with "data.table":

```
as.data.table(M)[, lapply(.SD, sample)]
```

---

Demo:

```
> M
  head1 head2 head3
1     1     a     A
2     2     b     B
3     3     c     C
4     4     d     D
> set.seed(1)              ## Just so you can reproduce my results
> M[] <- lapply(M, sample)
> M
  head1 head2 head3
1     2     a     C
2     4     c     A
3     3     b     D
4     1     d     B
```